# Preset dropdown for HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, input

I am trying to make a HTML form with a preset dropdown. The form is meant to be used frequently, so the preset menu is supposed to help the user choose common input options.

I cannot find any tutorials on how to do this anywhere, so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I do not want to use any external libraries, if possible.

By a preset dropdown, I mean something like this:

```js
var lastPreset = "preset1";

function previousPreset(element) {
 lastPreset = element.value;
}

function updatePresets(element) {
 var old = document.getElementById(lastPreset);
 if (old) {
  old.style.display = "none";
  for (var i = 0; i < old.childNodes.length; i++) {
   old.childNodes[i].required = false;
  }
 }
 var preset = element.value;
 var div = document.getElementById(preset);
 if (div) {
  div.style.display = "block";
  for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
   div.childNodes[i].required = true;
  }
 }
 lastPreset = preset;
}

function submitted() {
 console.log("Submitted!");
 return false;
}
```

```css
#preset2, #preset3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted();">
 <select onchange="updatePresets(this);" onfocus="previousPreset(this);">
  <option selected value="preset1">Preset 1</option>
  <option value="preset2">Preset 2</option>
  <option value="preset3">Preset 3</option>
 </select>
 <div id="preset1">
  <textarea required placeholder="Sample Text"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id="preset2">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div id="preset3">
  <input type="file">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is just a hacky mess I made in a few minutes to show the sort of behaviour that I am trying to achieve. I am just looking for any tutorials or guides on how to do this sort of thing. It seems like someone would have tried this before.

Thanks for any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a far better method involving classes [from looking at similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261252/jquery-select-menu-to-show-and-hide-certain-div-elements):

```js
function updatePresets(element) {
 var presets = document.getElementsByClassName("presets");
 var div = document.getElementById(element.value);
 for (var i = 0; i < presets.length; i++) {
  var preset = presets[i];
  preset.style.display = div === preset ? "block" : "none";
  for (var j = 0; j < preset.childNodes.length; j++) {
   preset.childNodes[j].required = div === preset;
  }
 }
}

function submitted() {
 console.log("Submitted!");
 return false;
}
```

```css
#preset2, #preset3 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return submitted();">
 <select onchange="updatePresets(this);">
  <option selected value="preset1">Preset 1</option>
  <option value="preset2">Preset 2</option>
  <option value="preset3">Preset 3</option>
 </select>
 <div id="preset1" class="presets">
  <textarea required placeholder="Sample Text"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id="preset2" class="presets">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div id="preset3" class="presets">
  <input type="file">
 </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```